# How to 'group by' to get the frequency counts as a new column?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I did this and I don't get expected results as it is not grouping as required
[image]

```
df1=pd.read_csv('https://cocl.us/sanfran_crime_dataset')
df1.drop(df1.columns.difference(['PdDistrict']),1,inplace=True)
df1=df1.rename(columns={'PdDistrict':'Neighborhood'})
df1['Counts']=df1.groupby('Neighborhood')['Neighborhood'].count() 
df1
```

Whats wrong with 4th line of code? groupby works fine if I do not assign it as a column but as I assign it as a column it doesn't even work.

Expected Output

[image: Expected output]

Comment: Please _type_ your code, data, and output. Do _not_ paste them as pictures.

Comment: I have pasted code i used. Please help !

Comment: The number of rows in the original table is 150500. The number of rows in the result is 9. How do you expect them to match?

Comment: When I simply do :  df1.groupby('Neighborhood')['Neighborhood'].count()
It groups 150500 rows into 9 rows and shows frequency in next to it as I want it to be. 

But when I assign this operation to add new column named "Counts", I am unable to do it.

Comment: How exactly do you want to combine a 150,500-row table and a 9-row table side by side?

Comment: I am very new to this. My end goal is to create a frequency count of existing column named "Neighborhood" in my data frame and add it  as a new column named "Counts"

Comment: You attempt to combine things that are not meant to be combined. Counts are aggregate measures. They do not belong to the same table with the raw data.

Comment: But please suggest me my solution. How do I achieve it without losing indexes.

Comment: Your question, as written, makes no sense and has no answer. Show us the expected output.

Comment: I have re-edited please see the expected output.

Comment: `df1.groupby('Neighborhood')['Neighborhood'].count()` _is_ your expected result. Just save it to a variable.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just write the 4th line as

```
df1 = df1.groupby('Neighborhood')['Neighborhood'].count()
```

If you write `df1['Counts']` you're adding a new column to the existing dataframe and the length of the new column (being the result of a `groupby`) doesn't match the length of the index of `df1`.

Comment: But this is not giving me the index values in output.

Comment: @BishwasBasnet what are the index values that you want to preserve?

Comment: Its  serial numbers starting from '0' vertically.